# Socket Programming in Python - Loop doesn't detect

Tags: python

The code below is related to socket programming using python.
Specifically, the client side. I am not sure why it doesn't read the loop?
It should read the loop inside the else par.
Is it because indentation or other reason ?

while True:

```
#Display main menu taken from server
menu = ClientSocket.recv(2048)
print(menu.decode('utf-8'))

#Input movie
func=input("Movie: ")
ClientSocket.send(str.encode(func))

if (func == '3'):
    print('Thank you! Come again.')
    break
else:

    #ask for showtime
    showtime = ClientSocket.recv(2048)
    print(showtime.decode('utf-8'))
    option = input('Pick a showtime: ')
    ClientSocket.send(str.encode(option))

    #ask for hall
    hallz = ClientSocket.recv(2048)
    print(hallz.decode('utf-8'))
    halls = input('\nPick a Hall: ')
    ClientSocket.send(str.encode(halls))

    #ask for number of seats
    numseats = ClientSocket.recv(2048)
    num_seats = input(numseats.decode('utf-8'))
    ClientSocket.send(str.encode(num_seats))

    #display seats
    seatsdisplay = ClientSocket.recv(2048)
    print(seatsdisplay.decode('utf-8'))

    #unavailable seats
    #cannotSeat = ClientSocket.recv(2048)

    #choose seats
    seats = ClientSocket.recv(2048)

    for x in range(int(num_seats)):
        pickedSeat = input(seats.decode('utf-8'))
        ClientSocket.send(str.encode(pickedSeat))
        msg = ClientSocket.recv(2048)
        #msg.decode('utf-8')
        if(msg.decode('utf-8') != '0'):
            print(msg.decode('utf-8'))
            print('')
            repickSeat = ClientSocket.recv(2048)
            try:
                pickedSeat = input(repickSeat.decode('utf-8'))
            except:
                print('Nope.')
            ClientSocket.send(str.encode(pickedSeat))
        else:
            msg = ''
```

Comment: Welcome ! Have you tried adding "print(1), print(2)...." everywhere to see if you enter the loop ?

Comment: already tried that, still the same :(

Comment: Could you be clearer ? At which line does the print() stop displaying ?